# Instruction not allowed [samba, nmbd, arm]

Tags: raspbian-jessie, pi-zero-w, samba

Right after I did `apt-get upgrade` on my Pi Zero W running Raspbian Jessie, I ended up with a broken samba setup. Trying `apt-get install -f` I get:

Note: I added Debian security repos, because I needed some packages that weren't in Raspbian's.

> dpkg: error processing package samba (--configure): subprocess
>   installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
>   Processing triggers for systemd (215-17+deb8u4) ... Errors were
>   encountered while processing: samba E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg
>   returned an error code (1)

Now, I could easily use FTP instead of samba,
but I really need nmbd running to have netbios names working. If I try
to `/usr/sbin/nmbd start` or `/usr/sbin/smbd start`

I get

> Illegal instruction

and it's not really a handled exception because I got this also by importing pycURL in python.

If you know any open alternative to nmbd, or if you know how to resolve this without reimaging the Pi please let me know.

Edit: Translation error

Comment: `Illegal instruction` - Are the repositories you added for the right CPU architecture?  (You want `armhf`, not `i386` or `amd64`.)  Please provide the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I did add the armhf repo. Now I replaced it with the deb-src ones, so I could try to build it by sources

Comment: Found out that debian armhf are for armv7 only. Pi0w has armv6. Now i have to recompile all samba dependencies that i updated with debian repos in my sources.list